# Lucene index corruption?

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

We are using hibernate search (5.6.5.Final) + lucene (5.5.5) and are noticing an intermittent issue on some of our servers when querying the index.

I'm not 100% sure what info I would need to provide to try and narrow down the problem, but we are seeing stack traces in the logs like so:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteArrayDataInput.readVInt(ByteArrayDataInput.java:105)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnumFrame.nextNonLeaf(IntersectTermsEnumFrame.java:254)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnumFrame.next(IntersectTermsEnumFrame.java:239)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnum.popPushNext(IntersectTermsEnum.java:345) 
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnum._next(IntersectTermsEnum.java:713)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.IntersectTermsEnum.next(IntersectTermsEnum.java:501)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.FilteredTermsEnum.next(FilteredTermsEnum.java:224)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyTermsEnum.next(FuzzyTermsEnum.java:240)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.TermCollectingRewrite.collectTerms(TermCollectingRewrite.java:67)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.TopTermsRewrite.rewrite(TopTermsRewrite.java:67)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQuery.rewrite(MultiTermQuery.java:331)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.rewrite(BooleanQuery.java:278)
 at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.rewrite(BooleanQuery.java:278)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LazyQueryState.rewrittenQuery(LazyQueryState.java:192)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LazyQueryState.search(LazyQueryState.java:103)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.updateTopDocs(QueryHits.java:241)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.QueryHits.<init>(QueryHits.java:136)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LuceneHSQuery.getQueryHits(LuceneHSQuery.java:360)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.engine.impl.LuceneHSQuery.queryEntityInfos(LuceneHSQuery.java:145)
 at org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.list(FullTextQueryImpl.java:197)
 at org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextQueryImpl.getResultList(FullTextQueryImpl.java:157)
```

The stack traces are not always the same (instead of from readVInt it might be in readVLong) but the exception is always ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

When I ran the check index tool (org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex) with the index pulled from the server, it reported no errors:

```
Segments file=segments_2 numSegments=1 version=5.5.5 id=e963cq35m2ov726h5wwj8aw39 format=
  1 of 1: name=_1t maxDoc=300616
    version=5.5.5
    id=e963cq35m2ov726h5wwj8aw38
    codec=Lucene54
    compound=false
    numFiles=10
    size (MB)=45.838
    diagnostics = {os=Linux, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.version=1.8.0_141, java.vm.version=25.141-b16, lucene.version=5.5.5, mergeMaxNumSegments=1, os.arch=amd64, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_141-b16, source=merge, mergeFactor=5, os.version=2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64, timestamp=1533021441077}
    no deletions
    test: open reader.........OK [took 1.027 sec]
    test: check integrity.....OK [took 0.040 sec]
    test: check live docs.....OK [took 0.000 sec]
    test: field infos.........OK [9 fields] [took 0.000 sec]
    test: field norms.........OK [7 fields] [took 0.041 sec]
    test: terms, freq, prox...OK [1231930 terms; 16245644 terms/docs pairs; 16300635 tokens] [took 1.719 sec]
    test: stored fields.......OK [601232 total field count; avg 2.0 fields per doc] [took 0.215 sec]
    test: term vectors........OK [0 total term vector count; avg 0.0 term/freq vector fields per doc] [took 0.000 sec]
    test: docvalues...........OK [0 docvalues fields; 0 BINARY; 0 NUMERIC; 0 SORTED; 0 SORTED_NUMERIC; 0 SORTED_SET] [took 0.000 sec]

No problems were detected with this index.
```

We rebuild the index on the master node and then copy it over to the slaves afterward. I'm thinking it may be a corruption issue around the copying but I would think the checker would report issues like that. Any ideas on what I can do to try and narrow this issue down?

Comment: How are you copying the index? You should really not try to mess with the state of the index without knowing what you do. Are you using the appropriate `filsystem-master`/`filesystem-slave` [directory providers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#directory-provider-table)? Are you also using one of the [built-in backends](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_backend), or do you just not perform any database change on slaves?

Comment: We are using the FSSlaveDirectoryProvider directory provider and JMS backend to push changes.

Comment: Ok, so at this point it's either a configuration issue or a bug. Please provide a list of all Hibernate Search properties you set and their values, both on the master and the slaves. Also please confirm you're not tampering with the index, either through Lucene native APIs or though filesystem accesses.

Comment: I'm not sure if this qualifies as tampering as we don't normally ever have issues with it and it has been running without issue for quite some time, but we rebuild the index on a regular basis (recently from every week to every night). The job runs on the master node: 1. Stop the background process that is running the JMS listener. 2. Run the mass indexer (pointed at a separate directory) and copy the resulting index after its done to the local master index 3. Restart the JMS listener.

Comment: Although it seems we are overriding the default reader strategy (SharingBufferReaderProvider) as we had issues with this process in the past. From the past ticket it seems we were getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: same segment _a has invalid changes; likely you are re-opening a reader after illegally removing index files yourself and building a new index in their place". The overridden reader just catches the error and closes the reader, then opens them again.

We've been rebuilding the index with this "fix" in place for some time and haven't really seen any issues with it.